# How can I add a condition to a code for a database?

Tags: python, pandas, database

I want to build a computer program, in Python code to use a large database (+400k lines).

I want to solve the following problem: to join any two students of a database, by possible "chains" of students. The student of these paths will have two common characteristics (class attended and year of promotion).

Example : If you want to do a basic chain of 2 students, student A and student B, these two students should have been in the same class during the same year to make the chain true.

If it is a 3 students chain, student A, B and C : student A should have been in  the same class the same year than student  B and student B in the same class the same year than student C to make the chain "true". If not, the chain is false.

Yet I have this code that has an issue, it doesn't count the year. The answer of the program is only based on the class attended and not the year. If two students have been in the same class but in very different year, the response will be True while it should be false.

The code so far :

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

class Student:
    
    """
    Object to interact with students
    """
    def __init__(self,
                 name,
                 df):

        self.name = name
        self.grades = set(df[df['student_name'] == name]['Grade'].tolist())
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'({self.name})'
    
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.name == other.name 
    
    @staticmethod
    def is_connected(student1,student2):
        """
        Check if two students are connected i.e if they were in the same class or graduated the same year
        :param student1: Student
        :param student2: Student
        """

        return len(student1.grades.intersection(student2.grades)) > 0
    
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.name, self.grade, self.year))

def get_info(row):
    """
    Given a df row of students, return the main information
    """
    return row.Year,row.Grade, row.name

def check_path(path):
    """
    Given a list of students check if it forms a path

    :param path: list[Students]
    """
    path_working = True
    for i in range(len(path)-1):
        path_working = Student.is_connected(path[i],path[i+1])
        if not path_working:
            break
    return path_working

def get_df(filename):
    """
    Read the csv filename of students
    """
    df = pd.read_csv(filename,sep = ';')
    return df


if __name__ == '__main__':

    filename = 'fileofstudents.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(filename,sep = ';')
    students = []
    with open('paths.txt','r') as f:

        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            name = line.strip()
            student = Student(name,df)
            students.append(student)
    
    #If you want to check if the given path is correct
    is_path = check_path(students)
    print(is_path)

    #If you want to check if there exists a path given the students
    paths = list(itertools.permutations(students))
    result = False
    for path in paths:
        result = check_path(path)
        if result:
            print(path)
            break
```

Does someone know how to add the second characteristic "year" to the code to make the code answers true only when students have been in the same classe the same year ?

Answer (score 0):

i) Ensure your database table has a column for class and name it something else but not CLASS as CLASS is a keyword.
ii) Your db table should have a column for year, don't name it year, you can name it yearFd, schoolYear or anything but not just YEAR.

iii) In your app program, write your labels and textfields (qLineEdits in Python)
they are to be filled and the system would then check if the information you provided correspond based on the condition you give to them. I am giving you an example below:
def functionName(self):
iv)

````
     xyz == "dept name" 
     stu = "SessionYear"                   
     if xyz and stu:
     sqlStatement = (write your db connection and sql statement here)
     print("ERROR")
                self.msgBox.setText("Student belongs to the right set")
                self.msgBox.setWindowTitle("Alert")
                self.msgBox.exec_()```
````